# Why code prints an error like "Object required"?

Tags: vba

i don't know why my code prints an error like "Object required" in line `stpos = ARange.End`

```
Public Function CreateNewWordDocument(TempPath)
 Dim wd
 Set App = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 App.Visible = True
 Set wd = App.Documents.Add(TempPath)
 Set CreateNewWordDocument = wd
End Function

Public Function AddNewParagraphRange(ARange)
 Dim NewParagraph
 Dim NewRange
 Dim I As Integer
 I = ARange.Paragraphs.Count
 ARange.InsertParagraphAfter
 Set NewRange = ARange.Paragraphs(I).Range
 NewRange.StartOf wdWord, wdMove
 Set AddNewParagraphRange = NewRange
End Function

Public Sub RunForword(CurDBPath)
 Dim R As Range

 Set R = doc.Range
 Dim aPart1
 Dim aPart2
 Dim aPart3
 Set aPart1 = AddNewParagraphRange(R)
 Set aPart2 = AddNewParagraphRange(R)
 Set aPart3 = AddNewParagraphRange(R)

End Sub


Public Function WriteParagraphLn(ARange, text, StyleName) As Range
 Dim stpos As Long
 stpos = ARange.End
 If Len(ARange) <= 2 Then
 ARange.InsertAfter text
 Else
 ARange.InsertParagraphAfter
 ARange.Document.Range(ARange.End, ARange.End + 1).Style = wdNormalStyleName

 ARange.InsertAfter text
 End If

 If StyleName <> "" Then _
 ARange.Document.Range(stpos, ARange.End).Style = StyleName

 Set WriteParagraphLn = ARange.Document.Range(stpos, ARange.End)
End Function


Sub Creat_doc()

Dim TempPath As String
Dim doc

Set doc = CreateNewWordDocument(TempPath)

With doc
 .PageSetup.TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2)
 .PageSetup.BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
End With
doc.Activate
Dim TextLine As String
TextLine = WriteParagraphLn("", "hello world", "Times New Roman")
doc.TypeText text:=TextLine
End Sub
```

Comment: Because the function expects the argument to be an instance of `Range`, but you are passing `""` instead. If an argument is supposed to be one thing only, then declare it as that thing, `ByVal ARange As Range`.

Comment: @GSerg ... and yet everyone raves about python! ;-)